# Unable to serialize post where using two parameters in controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to pass two parameters to an mvc controller from javascript. The first is a model and the second is a string.

Here is the html:

```
<input type="button" onclick="save(Json.Encode(@Html.Raw(model)), @Html.Raw(object.Id))" />
```

Here is the javascript:

```
function save(model, id) {

      $.ajax({
          url: '@Url.Action("SaveModel", "Test")',
          type: "POST",
          datatype: "json",
          data: { model: model, id: id }
          }
      });

  }
```

And here is the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveModel(Model model, string id)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

If I only pass the model parameter `data: { model: model }`, ***it works***. The post of the request becomes something like this:

```
AProperty   value1
AnotherProperty value2
AnArray[0][Property...
AnArray[1][Property...
etc.
```

But if I try to pass in both parameters `data: { model: model, id: id }` the post of the request becomes

```
model[AProperty]    value1
model[AnotherProperty]  value2
model[AnArray][0][Property...
model[AnArray][1][Property...
etc.
```

When the request reaches the controller the model object is instantiated, but all values has become null. I guess the serializer failed.

All help appreciated.

Comment: i solve that problem follows: i create property Id in my model and set id before post: **model.id = id**

Comment: This might be a workaround, but I like to know how I can pass one model plus another parameter to the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My colleague  solved it. You have to specify the content type and do stringify on the model, like this:

```
$.ajax({
      url: '@Url.Action("SaveModel", "Test")',
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json",
      data: JSON.stringify({ model: model, id: id })
      }
  });
```

Maybe this will help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to using this [JSON library](http://www.json.org/js.html) and take advantage of `stringify()`

```
$.ajax({
      url: '@Url.Action("SaveModel", "Test")',
      type: "POST",
      datatype: "json",
      data: JSON.stringify({ model: model, id: id })
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried that, but no good. All the values of the model are gone in the controller.

Comment: You need to see what is being sent in the request, have you tried Fiddler?

Comment: Yes. I can see the request using firebug in FF. If you look at my initial post I give some examples on what the post of the request contains. When I call the controller like this `data: model` the post is `AProperty value1` and everything works, but if I call the controller with `data: { model: model }` the post contains `model[AProperty] value1` and it doesn't work. But I have to call it `data: { model: model, id: id }` to be able to pass two parameters.

Comment: You were halfway there, man (see my latest post). Thanks anyway!